Printing images to transfer with laser printer
I'm trying to print pictures on blank return address labels on the glossy side (labels removed) to transfer them to wood.
I have seen this done on YouTube and have done it myself with this method having the local library print them for me on the laser printer there. I purchased a HP Color LaserJet Pro 3201DW Wireless Color Laser Printer to make it more convenient for me.
I can't get the pictures (images) to print correctly.
What are the correct settings for this printer to do this?

What does "I can't get the pictures (images) to print correctly" mean?

The pictures are spotty and the toner is in places it shouldn't be.

You're using stuff in a way that it's not supposed to be used. In computers, that's called a "kludge," and it should always be a last resort.
Anyway, it's not working.
Do it the proper way: Print the reverse image on t-shirt transfer paper, then press the image to the wood under a hot iron and wax paper.
